# Plotting two data frame variables against each other in shiny

Tags: r, plot, dataframe, shiny

I am trying to plot two data frame variables against each other in shiny (I am new to shiny and still trying to figure out reactivity). The idea is that user can choose any two variable from the drop down and R will plot them. First of all I am not entirely sure if I can do it the way I am trying to do. Secondly, I am getting an error:

Warning: Error in as.double: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Stack trace (innermost first):
    82: xy.coords
    81: plot.default
    80: plot
    79: renderPlot [app/Plotapp2.R#39]
    71: output$plot
     4: 
     3: do.call
     2: print.shiny.appobj
     1: print

Here's the code. Any help will be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
library(shiny)
All.choice = c ("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width","Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")


ui <- pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Plot 2 variables"),
sidebarPanel(
    selectInput(inputId = "x",
              label = "Choose the x axis",
              All.choice),
    selectInput(inputId = "y",
            label = "Choose the y axis",
            All.choice)
 ),
    mainPanel(

plotOutput("plot")
 )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

 x11 = reactive({
 x1 = input$x
 iris$x1
})

 y11 = reactive({
 y1 = input$y
 iris$y1
})
 output$plot = renderPlot({
 plot(x11,y11)
})
}

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Update: I changed the last line to

```
 plot(x11(),y11())
```

and the error message changed to:  need finite 'xlim' values

Comment: I made a change in last line to plot(x11(), y11()) and now the error that I get is:     need finite 'xlim' values

Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning in min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
Warning in max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
Warning: Error in plot.window: need finite 'xlim' values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `iris[[x1]]` and `iris[[y1]]` instead of `iris$x1` and `iris$y1`